# How to use Fabric v.1.2's "Private Data" in Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Since Hyperledger Fabric v1.2 there is the possibility to use "Private Data", see https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/whatsnew.html

Is there a way to implement "Private Data Collections" via Hyperledger Composer - or is this only possible at the Fabric level?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot use private data collections with composer.

Comment: Ok, so Hyperledger Composer does not provide the facility to configure private data. But does this also mean that it is not possible to configure Private Data on the Fabric level and deploy a Hyperledger Composer business network/application on top of it? Or is it possible to combine applications developed using Hyperledger Composer with Private Data - as long as one configures Private Data separately at the Fabric level?

Answer (score 2):

To configure private data you need to define a JSON file and include it as part of the instantiation request. It's not possible to pass this configuration to the `composer network start` command so you cannot configure the private collection for a business network.

Composer has no explicit APIs or knowledge of private data. You could use the getNativeAPI to gain access to the stub to interact with the chaincode private apis but that won't be enough

From a client side composer does not support the transient map for invoke, nor does it support peer targetting (which you could get around by defining unique connection profiles in a card) which you need in order to use private data. In theory again you could use the getNativeAPI call to gain access to the node sdk client and try and do it yourself by knowing how to construct the correct JSON and appropriate function to invoke on the composer runtime chaincode, but then you will need to do all the work of collecting the responses and submitting to the orderer and waiting for events, this is not something that is recommended or anything composer would support.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to write your private data implementation in golang so composer doesn't support such feature. Maybe you can start to learn chaincode for fabric.

Comment: In Fabric you can write chaincode in goLang as well as Node.js and Java is coming. You can also write client side applications in Go, Node and Java so there is more than Just GoLang available.